# Magento cant send order email after update

Tags: magento

Im new to Magento. I tried to update from 1.8.1 to 1.9.1. After the update everything seem to working perfect. But when you order products you dont get any emails.

I really dont know much about Magento so any hint would be amazing.

I get the following 2 exceptions during the process:

btw: "Ungültiger Blocktyp" means "Invalid Blocktype"

```
2015-04-30T08:03:43+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ungültiger Blocktyp:
Mage_Imprint_Block_Content' in /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/Mage.php:595

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ung\xC3\xBCltiger Blo...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('imprint/content', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(169): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('imprint/content', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(163): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(548): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<!--@vars\n{"sto...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(311): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<!--@vars\n{"sto...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->getProcessedTemplate(Array, true)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(508): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('7', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(813): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
2015-04-30T08:03:43+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ungültiger Blocktyp: Mage_Imprint_Block_Field' in /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ung\xC3\xBCltiger Blo...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('imprint/field', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(169): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('imprint/field', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(163): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(548): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('{{block type="i...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(530): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('{{block type="i...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(392): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->getProcessedTemplateSubject(Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(508): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('7', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(813): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/shop2/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like perhaps your order confirmation email template is making use of some custom blocks from an extension that has been uninstalled or is not properly installed. The reason I suspect this is because in your stack trace I see `{{block type="imprint/content"...}}`. When Magento tries to load this block, it is not finding it, which you can tell because it is trying to load `Mage_Imprint_Block_Content` and `Mage_Imprint_Block_Field` from core and not finding them. You should check your template and remove those directives.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure your cron job is up and running.

http://jakesharp.co/magento/magento-emails-not-sent/